# Live Reloading more than one npm Module

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have the following scenario:

Node Module 1 (NM1) and Node Module 2 (NM2). NM2 had as dependency NM1. NM1 has further (external) dependencies. I'm developing on both modules. So I'm searching for a live reloading mechanism (or implementing by myself) which detects:

- Changes on NM1 (incl. changes on dependencies)
- Changes on NM2 (incl. changes on dependencies)

So if I change code and the dependencies in NM1, in NM2 will be the new dependencies.

My Toolchain is: npm, npm scripts and Webpack 2 (incl. webpack-dev-server).

Thanks.

Comment: For development, shouldn't you use `npm link`?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran Thanks for your comment. Yes npm link is one part of the solution. But if I change a file, the watcher process have to start a build step, thereby the artifacts come to the other node module.